# Split a string in to words and numbers

Tags: java

I have a string as below.

> `sil(0.14,0.25) in(0.25,0.82) order(0.82,1.03) to(1.03,1.17) entertain(1.17,1.94) the(1.94,2.04) people(2.04,2.41) who(2.41,2.54) are(2.54,2.6) listening(2.6,3.13) to(3.13,3.29)` you, ..........

I have split the string as follow.

> ```
> sil
> 0.14
> 0.25
>
> in
> 0.25
> 0.82
>
> order
> 0.82
> 1.03
>
> to
> 1.03
> 1.17
> ```

What I want is to find the difference between the two numbers after each word. 
eg :  sil = 0.25 - 0.14
      in =  0.82 - 0.25

Please let me know how to do this task.

Thaks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

1. `.split()` by `" "` so you can get array like `{sil(0.14,0.25), in(0.25,0.82) ...}`
2. take each of this array and `.parse()` by splitting `","` and subtract first by second

   ```
   private static float parse(String s) {
      String str = s.substring(s.indexOf('(')+1, s.length()-1);
      String[] numbers = str.split(",");

      return Float.parseFloat(numbers[1]) - Float.parseFloat(numbers[0]);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s = "sil(0.14,0.25) in(0.25,0.82) order(0.82,1.03) to(1.03,1.17)            entertain(1.17,1.94) the(1.94,2.04) people(2.04,2.41) who(2.41,2.54) are(2.54,2.6) listening(2.6,3.13) to(3.13,3.29)";

       String[] sArray = s.split(" ");

       for(String str : sArray){
          String head = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('('));
          System.out.println(head + "=" +parse(str));
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot hilal. This is actually what I was looking for.I have a very little experience in String manipulation. Thanks again.